# Multiprocessor scheduling

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduling

With reference to Linux 2.4 and Unix SRV4  I don't understand if a real time process can preempt a time-sharing process ,before the latter expires its slicing time.
I think so , because this is why It has been introduced the real-time scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , it is possible.In Unix SRV4 there is the addition of preemption points (or safe places ) , and the entire code of a time sharing process is a safe place.